# C# project failed with java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: AFFERENT_COUPLINGS

Tags: c#-4.0, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I am facing issues while analyzing C# projects using sonar-runner.

```
**Sonarqube version: 5.1.1

Sonar-runner version: 2.4**

From the forums I found that AFFERENT COUPLINGS has been removed from sonarqube 5.1.1 version(core and java plugins). But I think, some other plugins are still searching for the field.

Could you please confirm the steps to be taken so that the build executes successfully?

Below is the log where the build is getting failed.

Execute decorators...
Decorators: ManualMeasureDecorator -> org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTrackingDecorator@47d7c0f4 -> QProfileEventsDecorator -> org.sonar.batch.design.ProjectDsmDecorator@193f239e -> org.sonar.batch.design.SubProjectDsmDecorator@3b6705 -> org.sonar.batch.design.DirectoryDsmDecorator@3be87961 -> FileTangleIndexDecorator -> SumDuplicationsDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.csharp.ndeps.decorators.CSharpDsmDecorator@1b78ee01 -> org.sonar.plugins.csharp.ndeps.decorators.CouplingDecorator@205191be -> org.sonar.plugins.csharp.gallio.UnitCoverageDecorator@33fb8aab -> UnitTestDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.core.security.ApplyProjectRolesDecorator@3a4dbf9f -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.DirectoriesDecorator@41a0c5d4 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.FilesDecorator@221c02f5 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TimeMachineConfigurationPersister@51e59665 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageAggregator@5d063451 -> f(lines) -> f(generated_lines) -> f(ncloc) -> f(generated_ncloc) -> f(classes) -> f(packages) -> f(functions) -> f(accessors) -> f(statements) -> f(public_api) -> f(comment_lines) -> f(public_undocumented_api) -> f(commented_out_code_lines) -> f(complexity) -> f(complexity_in_classes) -> f(complexity_in_functions) -> f(class_complexity_distribution) -> f(function_complexity_distribution) -> f(file_complexity_distribution) -> f(conditions_to_cover) -> f(uncovered_conditions) -> f(it_lines_to_cover) -> f(it_uncovered_lines) -> f(it_conditions_to_cover) -> f(it_uncovered_conditions) -> f(overall_lines_to_cover) -> f(overall_uncovered_lines) -> f(overall_conditions_to_cover) -> f(overall_uncovered_conditions) -> f(rfc) -> f(rfc_distribution) -> f(lcom4_distribution) -> f(package_cycles) -> f(package_tangles) -> f(package_feedback_edges) -> f(package_edges_weight) -> f(count_asserts) -> f(eloc) -> f(lines_to_cover) -> f(new_lines_to_cover) -> f(uncovered_lines) -> f(new_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_uncovered_conditions) -> f(new_it_lines_to_cover) -> f(new_it_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_it_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_it_uncovered_conditions) -> f(new_overall_lines_to_cover) -> f(new_overall_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_overall_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_overall_uncovered_conditions) -> org.sonar.batch.language.LanguageDistributionDecorator@25f34c7a -> org.sonar.batch.debt.DebtDecorator@821f10d -> org.sonar.batch.debt.NewDebtDecorator@6c5890a6 -> DirectoryTangleIndexDecorator -> org.sonar.batch.cpd.decorators.DuplicationDensityDecorator@55df4060 -> CountUnresolvedIssuesDecorator -> CountFalsePositivesDecorator -> CommentDensityDecorator -> f(file_complexity) -> f(class_complexity) -> f(function_complexity) -> f(assert_per_test) -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.LineCoverageDecorator@32834586 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.CoverageDecorator@48497a52 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.BranchCoverageDecorator@4ffdc291 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItLineCoverageDecorator@1cf0e69e -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItCoverageDecorator@bb49dea -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItBranchCoverageDecorator@7eeb73a6 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallLineCoverageDecorator@13f5d863 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallCoverageDecorator@715155d1 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallBranchCoverageDecorator@12d94676 -> org.sonar.batch.debt.SqaleRatingDecorator@2a80b9dc -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TendencyDecorator@2730b778 -> VariationDecorator
07:44:07.663 DEBUG - Release semaphore on project : org.sonar.api.resources.Project@c4e6697[id=96227,key=cs,qualifier=TRK], with key batch-cs
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Could anyone please help me on this?
I have struck at this point and my work is getting effected.
I have tried the solution mentioned at below link but it did not help me.
http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException-while-decorating-Java-file-td5034646.html
Error details:
Error during Sonar runner execution Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: AFFERENT_COUPLINGS
Please note that I am facing this issue while analyzing c# projects only.
Java projects are successfully pushed to sonar dashboards.

Comment: This problem has been resolved after using MSBuild Sonar Runner
Reference: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin

Comment: I am new to SonarQube and i didn't find any good docs to setup for VS2010. Looks like you are doing it and you have some knowledge. Please send me if you have any references. My id: prasadmcts@gmail.com. I am trying to setup for VS2010 and C# 4.0.